# Using props of a passed component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an abstract grid and my main component is a  and the table have the 3 components (like a normal table)   and  and I have an option to choose if I want to use the default TableBody, TableHeader or TableFooter or to pass in my own e.g. .

The question is how can I pass the tablebody2 to  and use the data like the default TableBody components.

Here is how I define what component to use (if null use default):

```
let templates = {
  header: null,
  body: <TableBody2 data={this.state.data}/>,
  footer: null
```

And here is how I'am passing the component to table:

```
<Table options={this.state.options} data={this.state.data} templates={templates}/>
```

And I'm not quite getting how I'am I suppose to access the data props of  inside

Resolved:
In my Table component I call my component(TableBody2) like this (this.props.templates.body(this.props)) and pass it the props of Table so I can access data like this

```
    function TableBody2(props){
  const tableData = props.data.map((data) => {
    return (
    <td key={data.userId}>{data.userId}</td>
  )
  });
  return (    
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    {tableData}
  </tr>
  </tbody>

  )
}
```

Comment: Edit your post, and just add one more space before <Table options...> in your post, then the code will appear

Comment: See my answer and try using the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and see what it logged under your browser console. Do you mind sharing what this `Table` component is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Render-Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern is your friend here. 
The crux of render-props pattern is: You pass a `function` as a property to your component, and then you can use that function in your `render()`

From Official Docs:

> a render prop is a function prop that a component uses to know what to render.

You can then enhance your `Table` component to provide more fine grained control over what is rendered. 
For e.x. You can define your `Table` component to accept 3 renderProps, let us call them `header`, `body`, `footer`

Your render method of `Table` can look like:

```
render() {
    {/* your main table code */}
    {this.prop.header && this.prop.header(this.prop.data)}
    {this.prop.body && this.prop.body(this.prop.data)}
    {this.prop.footer && this.prop.footer(this.prop.data)}
}
```

Sample usage could be:

```
<Table data={someData} 
       body={(data) => (<TableBody2 data={data} />)} />
```

You can take a look at [Downshift library code](https://github.com/paypal/downshift#render-prop-function), it uses render props amazingly to provide flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I must be sincere that the question is not very clear to me, but if you asking how you access props inside component (Table) then it is: `this.props.templates`

Answer (score 0):

In your receiving component you just need to access the data by using, for example, `this.props.data` or `this.props.template`. Or, you can try using `componentWillReceiveProps()` like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
}
```

Or in `constructor(props)` the same way as above if it's only a one-time operation.